# List Files That Do Not Contain String in Filename

Tags: powershell

I have two files:

`filename-0.1.211653-tests.jar`
`filename-0.1.211653.jar`

I'm trying to find a command that will filter out `filename-0.1.211653-tests.jar`.

Searching Stack Overflow I've tried:

1. `Get-ChildItem .\*.jar | Where-Object{!(Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "test")}`
2. `Get-ChildItem .\*.jar | where { "test" -notcontains $_}`
3. `gci |foreach-object{if (-not (select-string -inputobject $_ -Pattern "test")){$_}}`
4. `dir *.jar | select BaseName | where { "test" -notcontains $_}`

I don't mean to ask a repeated question, but none of those answers worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-Exclude` parameter:

```sh
Get-ChildItem *.jar -Exclude *-tests.jar
```

See [Example 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--get-child-items-using-the-exclude-parameter) from MS Docs.

**Note:** Using `-Filter` with `-Include` or `-Exclude` will not work:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jar

    Directory: C:\Users\User\Documents

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/14/2021   4:54 PM              2 filename-0.1.211653-tests.jar
-a----         6/14/2021   4:55 PM              2 filename-0.1.211653.jar

PS C:\Users\User\Documents> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jar -Exclude *-tests.jar

PS C:\Users\User\Documents>
```

However if you do it like this, it works fine:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> Get-ChildItem -Path $HOME\Documents\*.jar -Exclude *-tests.jar

    Directory: C:\Users\User\Documents

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/14/2021   4:55 PM              2 filename-0.1.211653.jar
```

---

Using `Where-Object` it would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jar | Where-Object BaseName -NotLike *-tests
```